# How to align a span at the right of a Bootstrap 5 card header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this [sample on Stackblitz](https://vhlfej.stackblitz.io). I want to align the span element that has the text "THIS" to the right, without increasing the height of the header. Whatever I do (d-flex / justify-content-right / position-absolute / etc.) increases the height of the header div.

Some ideas?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Links to other sites aren't adequate. It's very easy to show a Bootstrap demo _here_ using the editor. Please tag your Bootstrap version.